# scala type signature to allow numeric ops on members

Tags: scala, typeclass, generic-constraints

I have two case classes that are basically identical, except that one has Int and the other Double members. I'm trying to create a common trait that I can use for functions operating on either and allowing basic numeric operations. But so far i can't figure out how to use either the Numeric or Ops types:

```
trait Sentiment[A] {
  def positive: A
  def negative: A
}

case class IntSentiment(positive: Int, negative: Int) extends Sentiment[Int]
```

I would like to come up with a function constraint so that I can perform numeric ops on the members, something along the lines of:

```
def effective[A](sentiment: Sentiment[A]): A = {
  sentiment.positive - sentiment.negative
}
```

This does not work, and I figure i need to invoke the `Numeric` type class somehow, but the closest I've come is:

```
def effective[A](sentiment: Sentiment[A])(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = {
  num.minus(sentiment.positive,sentiment.negative)
}
```

Is there a type constraint/signature on `Sentiment` and/or `effective` I can define to actually just use `+` and `-` ops on the members directly?

Comment: Incidentally, generic numerics in plain Scala are boxed, so aren't all that fast.  You may not need them to be.  If you do, check out Spire.

Comment: Spire looks interesting. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import scala.Numeric.Implicits._

def effective[A : Numeric](sentiment: Sentiment[A]): A = {
  sentiment.positive - sentiment.negative
}
```